# Redirecting old domain to two new domains

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, multiple-domains

The issue at hand is redirecting selected pages from the `olddomain` to the `newdomain1` and `newdomain2`. Doing one domain is fairly straightforward, but it's different when handling two domains.

Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated!

**FILE: `.htaccess` (Old Domain Name's cPanel)**

> Code to allow redirects for two domain names. NOTE: This is the first line of code in the file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain1.example/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain2.example/ [L,R=301]
```

**FILE: `.htaccess` (Old Domain Name's cPanel)**

> Redirects old domain `olddomain` to new domain `newdomain1` (forcing pages that don't have redirects to load 404s on `domain1`)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://newdomain1.example/
```

> Problem to solve

Redirects listed below are not working. This code is added underneath the `RedirectMatch 301`.

**FILE: `.htaccess` (Old Domain Name's cPanel)**

`Redirect 301 /team/ https://newdomain1.example/about/our-team/
Redirect 301 /about/ https://newdomain2.example/about-us/`

Attempted code to resolve issue, but didn't work:

```
# Redirect olddomain.example/oldpage1 to newdomain1.example/newpage1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage1$ http://newdomain1.example/newpage1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect olddomain.example/oldpage2 to newdomain2.example/newpage2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage2$ http://newdomain2.example/newpage2 [L,R=301]
```

> Edit: May 29, 2023 - Top of file

Tasks at hand:

1. Redirect the homepage of oldwebsite to newwebsite1.
2. Redirect pages that don't exist on of oldwebsite to newwebsite1 so they 404 and not load the oldwebsite.
3. Redirect pages from oldwebsite to newwebsite1.
4. Redirect pages from oldwebsite to newwebsite2.

The oldwebsite has been split into two different websites, and content was moved to two domains instead one which is more typical.

1. From the below code, tried commenting out both `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to see if this would resolve the issue of redirecting all links to the homepage. Single redirects are meant to redirect to specific pages.

```
     # BEGIN 301 Redirects - Old Domain to New Domain
     # Website Name
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newwebsite1.example/ [L,R=301]
     # END 301 Redirects - Old Domain to New Domains
```

2. The code below is meant to ensure the oldwebsite's homepage redirects to newwebsite1's homepage.

```
     # BEGIN 301 Redirects 
     # Website Name
     # 301 Redirects - New Website - Homepage Only
     RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://newwebsite1.example/
```

3. From the below code, we're wanting one page from oldwebsite to redirect to one page on newwebsite1. There are over 100 redirects for newwebsite1.

`Redirect 301 /about/ https://newwebsite1.example/about/`

4. From the below code, we're wanting one page from oldwebsite to redirect to one page on newwebsite2. There are over 100 redirects for newwebsite2.

`Redirect 301 /team/ https://newwebsite2.example/our-team/`

> Edit: May 30, 2023 - This code is listed at the bottom:

```
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 300
   php_value max_input_vars 4000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 1024M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 300
   php_value max_input_vars 4000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 1024M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

This concludes everything from the file has been added.

Status: Only the oldwebsite and oldwebsite's pages are redirecting to newwebsite1's homepage.

Comment: Do these domains point to the same place or different servers/vHosts? So, what are you wanting to redirect and to where? The first code block is a bit odd (but it depends what you are trying to do). The second and third code blocks are OK, but you should avoid mixing mod_alias and mod-rewrite (the first and last code blocks). The last code block is OK (although the `Host` check is redundant if the olddomain points to a different server) and the order of directives is important. Please include your complete `.htaccess` file and the URLs you want to redirect.

Comment: Do you have any files still residing at olddomain (if it is pointing to a different server)? Btw, the "description" of the rule you have written before the rule does not seem to describe what it does?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You appear to have 2 different contents for the single .htaccess which is impossible - what are the paths for each .htaccess?    Where did you add the redirect Match?

Comment: Also, where did you add the Redirect and RedirectMatch rule?  If they came after the RewriteRules they are likely not getting hit.

Comment: @MrWhite regarding your first comment - olddomain, newdomain1 and newdomain2 are all on the same shared hosting. The code is mostly taken from online.

Comment: @MrWhite regarding your second comment - olddomain is on the same shared hosting server. The "description" is likely incorrect.

Comment: @davidgo regarding your first comment - It's not possible to redirect olddomain to newdomain1 and newdomain2? All three domains live on the same shared hosting server. The "RedirectMatch 301" is meant to redirect all traffic from olddomain to newdomain1 which would include 404s of pages that no longer exist and links that do exist.

Comment: @davidgo - regarding your second comment - The second rewrite is not working correct `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain2.com/ [L,R=301]`.

Comment: Your question and statements make 0 sense.  Again, you have listed the same .htaccess file with 3 different contents - did you mean the first to be the old and  then have 2/new ones?

Comment: @davidgo, that's correct.

Comment: @davidgo, are you suggesting there should be an htaccess file for newdomain1 and another htaccess file for newdomain2. Then have the redirects listed in those files? From my understanding, there should only be one htaccess file. But please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, there should only be one `.htaccess` file from which these redirects are implemented (since you only have one domain from which you are wanting to redirect).

Comment: "olddomain, newdomain1 and newdomain2 are all on the same shared hosting" - and all are pointing to the same directory on the filesystem (including newdomain1 and newdomain2)?! (If the olddomain points to the same place then the first two code blocks really make no sense?) As per my first comment, "Please include your complete `.htaccess` file and the URLs you want to redirect from/to" - without this information we cannot answer this question, since there is nothing particularly wrong with the last two code blocks (except, as stated, you should not mix redirects from both modules).

Comment: @mrwhite beat me to that comment. I was literally typing it as yours popped up.

Comment: Also, if this is all one sequential file the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain2.com/ [L,R=301]` is likely matching everything and anything after is being ignored.

Comment: I voted to close this question as needing more details and clarity for the reasons above.

Comment: This is only for MrWhite. @MrWhite For privacy reasons I cannot disclose the website links. Server PHP.INI details are pending to be added. That would mean all the contents from .htaccess have been added.

Comment: @MrWhite the PHP.INI code has been added. Everything in this file that's active code is now added. The website does have "Begin WordPress" standard code, but it's deactivated. So I did not include that.

Comment: Are all three of your domain configured separately in cPanel as add on domains?  Do each of them have a separate document root directory?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The domains have their own cPanel accounts on the same server. The .htaccess file listed above is for oldwebsite.

Comment: Are all the separate pieces that you posted above from a single `.htaccess` file?  Are the pieces in the same order as they are in the file?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller From May 29 edits to the bottom. They are in order from top to bottom from there.

Comment: "Redirect pages that don't exist on of oldwebsite" - So, "pages" are physical files (and directories?) - no front-controller/router script? Do these URLs all have a consistent file extension like `.html` or `.php`? (Although if you have URLs like `/about/` and `/team/` as suggested in sections #3 and #4 then that could imply you do have a front-controller/router, unless these are physical directories and you are serving the directory index from these directories?)

Comment: @MrWhite All three are WordPress websites (newwebsite1, newwebsite2,  oldwebsite). For pages `/about/` is a page, `/about/team/` would be a page, then `/team/` would be an inner page. There would be no need to use front-controller/routers.

Comment: "There would be no need to use front-controller/routers." - But it is the WordPress "front-controller" that determines what URLs map to pages, so it's impossible to implement "#2 Redirect pages that don't exist on of oldwebsite to newwebsite1" in `.htaccess` - since only WordPress knows what URLs map to pages and what does not. UNLESS, by "pages" you really mean physical files/assets (which is what your rule is doing)?!

Comment: ... although I suppose you don't really _need_ to implement #2 specially (providing you are not expecting oldwebsite to serve any content), since you just redirect _everything else_ to newwebsite1?